# Using SYMGETN to Specify Number of Times to Loop in %DO Statement

Tags: sas

I am trying to pass a variable value from a dataset to a Macro and use it in the `do` loop.

```
data work.b;
    set work.a;

    if _N_ = 1 then call symput('foo', foo_var);
run;

%macro bar(max_loop_count);
    %do i = 1 %to &max_loop_count;

        * Some data steps here ;

    %end;
%mend;

%bar(symgetn('foo'));
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
ERROR: Required operator not found in expression: &max_loop_count 
ERROR: The %TO value of the %DO I loop is invalid.
ERROR: The macro BAR will stop executing.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: is there a specific reason to use symgetn instead of &foo at macrocall? http://www.lexjansen.com/nesug/nesug04/pm/pm13.pdf At the top of page 2 it says:"Conversely, SYMGET is a SAS language 
function
 that returns the 
value of a macro variable to the DATA step during DATA step execution." My guess would be the function symgetn is only for execution inside a datastep, so you can not use it in a macro call. But i can not backup this with more references, so i only post this as comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your macro call would result in the `%DO` loop having this upper bound `symgetn('foo')`. You cannot use `SYMGETN()` in macro code since it is a data step function, so that is why you got an error that the upper bound wasn't a number.

Just pass the value of the macro variable in the macro call.

```
%bar(&foo);
```

Comment: yep this is the correct answer. Can't believe I missed that.